# circle action on the non orientable disk bundle over the circle.

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is there a way to "parametrize" the non-orientable $D^2$-bundle over $S^1$ so that one can give a homeomorphism between $D^2\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}S^1$ and the cartesian product between a Mobius strip and an interval?

Can this homeomorphism be meda equivariant with respect to a circle action on $D^2\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}S^1$?

Comment: Write it as a quotient of the trivial bundle $D^2\times S^1$, on which you can use coordinates, and use equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. I have done that but what I want to prove by doing this is that $D^2\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}S^1$ is homeomorphic to the cartesian product of a Möbius strip with an interval and I can't seem to do it. I regard $D^2$ as the unit disk in complex plane. Then the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $D^2$ would just be to take the conjugate. I am unsure as to what the  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action on $S^1$ should be.

Comment: Well, I suggest to edit the question to incldue all the information relevant to what you want to do. What you wrote inyour comment is quite more than what you wrote in the actual question!

Comment: I'm sorry I have edited it. Could you suggest a way to go in order to prove the homeomorphism?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $D^2\times_{\mathbb Z_2}S^1$ (and what are the actions you have in mind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J=[-1,1]$. One can write the band as the quotient of $M=(J\times S^1)/\sim$ of the cilinder $J\times S^1$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by $(t,z)\sim(-t,-z)$.

Since everything in sight is compact and Hausdorff, we have $M\times I=((J\times S^1)/\sim)\times I=(J\times S^1\times I)/\approx$ with $\approx$ the equivalence relation  generated by $(t,z,u)\approx(-t,-z,u)$.

On the other hand, you can easily identifty the disc $D^2$ with $J\times I$, and the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on it with $(t,u)\leftrightarrow(-t,u)$, so that $D^2\times_{\mathbb Z_2}S^1$ can be seen as $(J\times I)\times_{\mathbb Z_2}S^1$, which is $(J\times I\times S^1$ modulo the relation $(t,u,z)\sim(-t,u,-z)$.

It should be clear howto do what you want now.